# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 when using postgresql database in .net 6 app

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, connection-string, .net-6.0

trying to update my database via dotnet ef database update, however the build starts and succeeds and then errors out with the following:

```
    System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

worth mentioning that my appsettings.json is in the api solution, and my dbcontext file is in my data access layer

```
appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "prattleDatabase": "Host=localhost; Database=prattle; Username=develop; Password=develop123;"
  }
}
```

programs.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext <PrattleContext> (option =>
    option.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("prattleDatabase")));
```

and my dbcontext:

```
   public class PrattleContext : DbContext 
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public PrattleContext()
        {

        }

        public PrattleContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            var dbConnectionInfo = builder.Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("prattleDatabase").Value;

            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("dbConnectionInfo");

        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build configuration again.

This should work for you.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       var connectionstring = _configuration.GetConnectionString("prattleDatabase");
       optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionstring);

    }
```